# Auto-connection of shapes dropped in WPF

Tags: c#, dynamic, wpf-controls, adorner

How can I make WPF dynamic lines be connected as done at 9m58sec time of https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DijfgmT1hs4 (just for a visual reference)? Just bringing other element a bit closer should create a connection as at above reference.
Could you advise the code/trick on how do it in C#/WPF?

Added afterwards:
Are there settings of ConnectorAdorner OR ConnectionAdorner OR Connection OR Designer Canvas to be tuned and what specific settings ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/xaml-tools/creating-a-ui-by-using-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019 help (look under snaplines)?

Comment: Thanks for tip, @Hayden, it is a bit different what I am looking for.
At 9m58 blocks got automatically connected once brought closer to each other, so there is no need to pull it from connector "Y". I am trying to identify the setting allowing doing that in WPF...